# af:popup is throwing required field validation error as soon as it opens (Jdev version 11.1.2.4)

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

Today I came across one exception for which I am not able to find the root cause as this error is very unpredictable.

My requirement is simple, I am developing the ADF form where I am performing simple DML operation.
For adding new record , I am using popup. Issue comes here, whenever I click on Add button popup opens up and it automatically throws the required field validations.
Please go through below popup code for your reference. (Jdev version 11.1.2.4)

```
<af:popup childCreation="deferred" autoCancel="enabled" id="p1" popupFetchListener="#{pageFlowScope.bean.onPopupFetch}"
contentDelivery="lazyUncached"  popupCanceledListener="#{pageFlowScope.bean.onCancelPopup}">
<af:dialog id="d1" dialogListener="#{pageFlowScope.bean.onDialogListener}"
                                   type="okCancel">
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.Code.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.Code.hints.label}" required="#{bindings.Code.hints.mandatory}"     columns="#{bindings.Code.hints.displayWidth}" maximumLength="#{bindings.Code.hints.precision}" shortDesc="#{bindings.Code.hints.tooltip}" id="it1">
<f:validator binding="#{bindings.Code.validator}"/>
  <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.Code.format}"/>
 </af:inputText>
 <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.NotifInd1.inputValue}"
   label="#{bindings.NotifInd1.label}"
   required="#{bindings.NotifInd1.hints.mandatory}"
   shortDesc="#{bindings.NotifInd1.hints.tooltip}" id="soc1">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Received" itemValue="R" id="si2"/>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Send" itemValue="S" id="si1"/>
   </af:selectOneChoice>
   <af:inputText value="#{bindings.BlockOccur.inputValue}"
    label="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.label}"
     required="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.mandatory}"
     columns="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.displayWidth}"
     maximumLength="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.precision}"
     shortDesc="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.tooltip}" id="it3">
     <f:validator binding="#{bindings.BlockOccur.validator}"/>
      <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.BlockOccur.format}"/>
     </af:inputText>
     <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Name.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.Name.hints.label}"
       required="#{bindings.Name.hints.mandatory}"
        columns="#{bindings.Name.hints.displayWidth}"
        maximumLength="#{bindings.Name.hints.precision}"
        shortDesc="#{bindings.Name.hints.tooltip}" id="it4">
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Name.validator}"/>
         </af:inputText>
          </af:panelFormLayout>
          <f:facet name="buttonBar"/>
          </af:dialog>
             </af:popup> 

<af:commandButton text="Add" id="cbInsert" immediate="true">
  <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="::p1" triggerType="action" align="afterEnd"/>
   </af:commandButton>
```

In popupFetchListener I am performing simple createInsert operation and on cancel listener Rollback.

Kindly suggest any solution for this issue.
I am using same approach in 2-3 places but there it is not throwing any error but in this case I am not able to resolve this.

Tried Workarounds:
 1. I tried keeping immediate= true for all the fields in popup, the issue got resolved but it will not throw any validation error even if user didnt enter required field, so this is not desirable.

2. keeping SkipValidation= true/skipDataControl. This is not working

Please let me know if anyone knows better approach.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting you button's **partialSubmit** attribute to **true**, you need to change the **triggerType** to **click** in the showPopupBehavior component.

```
<af:commandButton text="Add" id="cbInsert" partialSubmit="true">
   <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="::p1" triggerType="click" align="afterEnd"/>
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **CreateInsert** use **Create** Operation .

Answer (score 0):

Delete required = #{***you code**} line from all the fields.

Example--> Delete this **required="#{bindings.Name.hints.mandatory}"**

```
 <af:inputText value="#{bindings.BlockOccur.inputValue}"
    label="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.label}"
      *****required="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.mandatory}"*****---->Delete this line in all the fields of Popup PanelFormLayout code
     columns="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.displayWidth}"
     maximumLength="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.precision}"
     shortDesc="#{bindings.BlockOccur.hints.tooltip}" id="it3">
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.BlockOccur.validator}"/>
     <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#    {bindings.BlockOccur.format}"/>
     </af:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but today I have faced the same issue, what I have done its delete the required tag in the component, and create a binding: (on the fetch of the popup) set the required attribute to true
"socBinding.setRequired(true);"
Hope this help some one else

Answer (score -1):

I found what causes this bug. This is an empty view object (0 rows). A solution: fill at least one line in the view object.

All attributes of my form had the required property = false. Yet it caused "and it automatically throws the required field validations." As if I pressed a button (without immediate = true). Validation worked at Entity level.

I did not touch SkipValidation. It defaults to false.

P.S. Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.0.0